# satisfying package dependencies

Tags: ros, rosdep, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have package that depends on the willow garage pr2_cockpit package.  Is there a way to inform a user that this dependency exists if the package is not already installed (besides looking through the output of rosmake or the package manifest file and checking manually)?  I tried adding "ros-diamondback-pr2-cockpit" as an external dependency in the manifest file.  However, rosdep install for my package failed with the following error:

rosdep install <package_name>
Failed to find rosdep ros-diamondback-pr2-cockpit for package <package_name> on OS:ubuntu version:10.04
ERROR: ABORTING: Rosdeps [u'ros-diamondback-pr2-cockpit'] could not be resolved

Any suggestions of a structured way to install external ros packages would be nice.  Is rosinstall the only other option?

Thanks for any help.

marc

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9880/satisfying-package-dependencies/) by [mkillpack](https://answers.ros.org/users/157/mkillpack/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At the moment installation instructions usually consist of

1. install the following debian packages: ros-diamondback-foo ros-diamondback-bar
2. install this rosinstall file http://example.com/example.rosinstall

In general ros packages are not designed to be installed via rosdep.  Though it does work.  There are some tools in development to facilitate the installation of larger systems.  However the above system so far works in most cases.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) on 2013-01-20**:
The link seems broken now

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When adding an external dependency, you also have to supply a rosdep.yaml file which maps your dependency name to a debian/ubuntu/whatever package. That's why you get the error message. However, as Tully said, it's not a good idea to try and install ROS packages via rosdep.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1